# How to write a Parallel.ForEach with one fixed parameter and another one from the collection?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a foreach method like this one:

```
public void Initialize(ClassB fixed)
{
    foreach (ClassA item in itemCollection)
    {
        this.InitializeStock(fixed, item);
    }
}
```

I would like to use a Parallel.ForEach with this one but not sure on how to do it. I cannot set the fixed parameter as a class attribute as the Initialize method is already called from another Parallel.ForEach.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not clear what the problem is. This should be fine:

```
public void Initialize(ClassB fixed)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(itemCollection, item =>
    {
        this.InitializeStock(fixed, item);
    });
}
```

The `fixed` variable will be captured by the lambda expression so that it can be used when calling `InitializeStock`.

EDIT: If you really don't want lambda expressions:

```
private class ClassBHolder
{
    private readonly ClassB fixed;
    // Foo is the class which has the Initialize method
    private readonly Foo container;

    internal ClassBHolder(ClassB fixed, Foo container)
    {
        this.fixed = fixed;
        this.container = container;
    }

    internal void Execute(ClassA item)
    {
        container.InitializeStock(fixed, item);
    }
}

public void Initialize(ClassB fixed)
{
    ClassBHolder holder = new ClassBHolder(fixed, this);
    Parallel.ForEach(itemCollection, holder.Execute);
}
```

... but really, which would you rather read?

Comment: Oh, I was trying to call the Parallel.ForEach passing directly a delegate. Will try this solution. Anyway I don't like anonymous methods at all. Is this possible with normal methods and a delegate?

Comment: @SoMoS: You should learn to embrace anonymous methods; there _extremely_ useful.  If you really don't want to, you'll need to create a separate class, [the way the compiler does](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html) for you when you use an anonymous method.

Comment: @SLaks: well, I ended with one line anonymous so I feel ok with it. Anonymous methods makes me spend more time trying to understand what's going on. But I agree that sometimes they're good (like this one).

Comment: @SoMoS: You should take out the time to understand how they work.  Especially when combined with LINQ, they can make your code much simpler and more readable.

Comment: @SoMoS: Think about the work that the compiler does for you when there's a lambda expression capturing a variable (this is a lambda expression, not an anonymous method). Then be glad you don't have to do it yourself. You *can* do it without anonymous functions - you can create a class yourself to hold the fixed value if you really want - but why bother? It's boiler-plate code.

Comment: @both: in this case I agree, the lambda is much better. I just don't like them when they get too complicated and prefer the new class to create simpler to read code. Thanks for sharing knowledge.

Comment: @SoMoS: See my edit for what you'd need to do without an anonymous function. "Simpler to read code" - really?

Comment: @Jon: Ey, hold on. I already told you that I agree! :) You're right in this case!

Comment: @SoMoS: The more you use lambda expressions, the happier you're likely to become with them. While I would *usually* stick to very short anonymous functions, for things like `Parallel.ForEach` it makes a lot of sense to have several-line ones. Of course you could always use a tiny lambda expression which just calls out to a "regular" method with as many parameters as you need. That's what you've got here, effectively.

Comment: @JonSkeet - You are an **actual** legend. I'm 2/3rd through your book so I really should've known this :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here try this:

```
public void Initialize(ClassB fixed)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(itemCollection, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 },
                (item, i, j) =>
                     {

                         this.InitializeStock(fixed, item);

                     });
}
```